# pandas.DataFrame.mul matching on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame (ignore the indices of the DataFrame)

```
    Tab  Ind  Com  Val
4   BAS    1    1   10
5   BAS    1    2    5
6   BAS    2    1   20
8   AIR    1    1    5
9   AIR    1    2    2
11  WTR    1    1    2
12  WTR    2    1    1
```

And a pandas series

```
Ind
1    1.208333
2    0.857143
dtype: float64
```

I want to multiply each element of the Val column of the DataFrame with the element of the series that has the same Ind value. How would I approach this? pandas.DataFrame.mul only matches on index, but I don't want to transform the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `pandas.DataFrame.join` could solve your problem:

```
temp = df.join(the_series,on='Ind', lsuffix='_orig')
df['ans'] = temp.Val*temp.Ind
```

Output

```
    Tab  Ind  Com  Val        ans
4   BAS    1    1   10  12.083330
5   BAS    1    2    5   6.041665
6   BAS    2    1   20  17.142860
8   AIR    1    1    5   6.041665
9   AIR    1    2    2   2.416666
11  WTR    1    1    2   2.416666
12  WTR    2    1    1   0.857143
```

Or another way to achieve the same using a more compact syntax ([thanks W-B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/w-b))

```
df1['New']=df1.Ind.map(the_series).values*df1.Val
```

Comment: Shorter your lines : -) `df1['New']=df1.Ind.map(s).values*df1.Val`